# How to Add Metadata to model in View by fluent validation in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

I have an ASP.NET MVC project. I have a model such this:

```
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidation))]
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
}
```

I have an strong view by above model.

I create a validator by fluent validation for my model. this is my code :

```
 public PersonValidation()
 {
        RuleSet("Update", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(t => t.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Error Null Name").When(t => t.ModelStatus == ModelStatus.Update);
        });
}
```

I want to create a RuleSet that add a metadata to some of my models field such Name in html file(View). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use WithName extension to specifies a custom property name to use within the error message.

```
public PersonValidation()
     {

                RuleFor(t => t.Name).NotNull().WithName("Name").WithMessage("Error Null Name");
    }
```